# displaying a message as pop up when my condition is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, popup

I need a pop up message whenever this if conditions run. Code below is here

**Code is this**

```
  <?php if(isset($session->data['GlobalMessage'])) { ?>
                     <div class="errors">
                      <?php echo $session->data['GlobalMessage']; 
                      unset($session->data['GlobalMessage']);?>

                     </div>
   <?php }
```

how can i display this message as pop up. Somebody please guide me. whenever this conditions is true the anchor tag is triggered and the message is displayed in this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger"></a>

   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have done all the styling for this and using this. problem is how i get triggered the anchor tag when the condition is true.

Comment: the html code is from one that is running . i will replace the message inside it modal body div

Comment: `$msg = "warning, it's true!"; echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '"); </script>';`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "popup"? Do you want a normal JS message box?

in this case you could use something like that:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
       , 'alert('.$session->data['GlobalMessage'].');'
       , '</script>';
```

but the code you provided is not good. So perhaps you should mind correcting it...

EDIT:
I see you have edited your post and what you want is a modalbox.

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. You could pass the session variable to a JS variable and check your condition in pure JS. Otherwise you could "show" your modalbox with JS from within your PHP code similairly as I posted before (just replace the alert with the right code needed to show your modalbox. It should be something like myModalBox.open() )

Comment: i have made the above pop for login page

Comment: whenever user clicks on login this popup appears.

Comment: Don't be to sure alert can output a variable like that. Especially (as I have noticed) boolean variables

Comment: but it appears when the user clicks the login button. in this case i want to click it itself

Comment: kindly could you explain it a little in your answer via code

Comment: @Core-Update with any of the method

Comment: @Andreas well normally you do not store a boolean value in a "globalMessage", but yes, you are right... in such a case there could be a problem displaying it. Thanks for remarking it

Comment: That code is an XSS security hole. if you can get `GlobalMessage` to be a fragment of html that closes the alert with a script error (probably silent) and sends all the cookies to `http://malici0us.c0m/session-collector-lol`. Then anyone viewing that page would execute the script tag you injected and their cookies would be sent. The information can be used to login as that user from the attacker's machine.